# Wrap Lines to Lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a list of lines containing **text links** in a HTML file that I want to transform into **hyperlinks** and **li lists** in **JavaScript**.

Example :

> ```
> <ul>
>    links
>    links text
>    links
> </ul>
> ```

to

> ```
> <ul>
>    <li><a href='links'>links</a></li>
>    <li><a href='links'>links</a> text</li>
>    <li><a href='links'>links</a></li>
> </ul>
> ```

This script transforms text links into hyperlinks :
[http://jsfiddle.net/RH8f6/94](http://jsfiddle.net/RH8f6/94/)

I tried to do the same for adding li tags to each lines:

```
//Wrap each line with li tags
       $('#links').ready(function() {
        // Get each ul
        $('ul').each(function(){
            // Get the content
            var str = $(this).html();
            // Select each lines starting with url
            //trim blank space before and include text after the links)
            var regex = /(http.*?).*/ig
            // Wrap each new line in textarea with li tags
            var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<li>$1</li>");
            // Echo link
            $(this).html(replaced_text);
        });
    });
```

... and it doesn't work. I wish to do the multiple replacement preferably in one single **JavaScript** function.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: isn't that your demo turns the plain texts into links OK?

Comment: You are using invalid HTML markup, you shouldn't expect it to work as 'expected'. BTW, you shouldn't use any regex to parse HTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @KingKing Yes the demo turns the plain text links into hyperlinks and it works

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do something like this:

```
$('ul>a').wrap("<li/>");
```